# $n$th derivative of $\sin(f(x))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, pattern-recognition, chain-rule

This problem came up in some math that I am working out on my own, not from a textbook, so there may not be any solution.

$$g(x) = \sin(f(x))$$

For any polynomial function $f(x)$,

$$g'(x)=\cos(f(x))f'(x)$$

$$g''(x)=-\sin(f(x))f'(x)^2+f''(x)\cos(f(x))$$

$$g'''(x)=-\cos(f(x))f'(x)^3-3\sin(f(x))f'(x)f''(x)+\cos(f(x))f'''(x) \\ \vdots$$

As you can see, each one is much more complex than the last, and takes much longer to evaluate than the last.

Is there pattern to find $g^{(n)}(x)$ without just brute-forcing it with the chain rule?

EDIT: To make the question more specific to my case, $f(x)$ is a polynomial function, and I only need to find $g^{(n)}(x)$ at $x=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: You can obtain $\sin(f(x))$ as the imaginary part of $e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x)=i f(x)$. So one might as well consider $e^{g(x)}$ instead, which should be a bit simpler. (Especially since each successive derivative contains $e^{g(x)}$ as an overall factor.)

Comment: Micah directed you to Faà di Bruno's formula before I saw the question, but your comment suggested you want to understand the coefficients.  I've posted an answer explaining that via its application to the fourth derivative. $\qquad$

Answer (score 7):

You want [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: Holy crap that formula is insane! How did I not know about this?

Comment: I can't understand the part with $m_1, m_2, ...$ and I can't come close to understanding what tuples are. Do you think you could give some simpler form for the $g(x)$ I have shown?

Comment: @Polygon: Since the derivatives of $\sin x$ are periodic, there should be some simplification (though maybe not too much). I don't have time to get into it right now, but I may post another (non-community-wiki) answer with a more detailed solution sometime tonight if somebody else doesn't get there first...

Comment: @Polygon : I've posted an answer devoted to explaining where the coefficients come from, via a concrete example. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Micah has already referred you to Faà di Bruno's formula.  Your comment suggests a difficulty understanding the coefficients.  One way to look at it is this.  Say you want
$$
\frac{d^4}{dx^4} \cos(f(x)).
$$
First solve the problem as if you were differentiating with respect to a different variable each time; then let the variables coalesce into just one variable and collect all the like terms.  In order to do that, first understand that there are $15$ ways to partition a set of four things:
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
4321 & \text{1 part} \\
\hline
432/1 & \text{2 parts,} \qquad 3+1 \\
431/2 \\
421/3 \\
321/4 \\
\hline
43/21 & \text{2 parts,} \qquad 2+2 \\
42/31 \\
41/32 \\
\hline
43/2/1 & \text{3 parts,} \qquad 2+1+1 \\
42/3/1 \\
41/3/2 \\
32/1/4 \\
31/2/4 \\
21/4/3 \\
\hline
4/3/2/1 & \text{4 parts} 
\end{array}
$$
Now we apply that:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_3\,\partial x_2\,\partial x_1} \cos(f) \\[15pt]
= {} & \cos'(f) \frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_3\,\partial x_2\,\partial x_1} & & {[}4{]} \\[15pt]
& {} + \cos''(f) \left( \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_3\,\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_3\,\partial x_1}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \right. & & {[}3+1{]} \\[5pt]
& \phantom{mmmmmm} {} + \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_2\,\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} + \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_3\,\partial x_2\,\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4} & & {[}3+1{]} \\[5pt]
& \phantom{mmmmmm} {} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2\,\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3\,\partial x_1} & & {[}2+2{]} \\[5pt]
& \phantom{mmmmmm} \left. {} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3\,\partial x_2} \right) & & {[}2+2{]} \\[15pt]
& {} + \cos'''(f) \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right. & & {[}2+1+1{]} \\[5pt]
& \phantom{mmmmmm} {} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_4\,\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3\,\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & & {[}2+1+1{]} \\[5pt]
& \phantom{mmmmmm} \left. {} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3\,\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2\,\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \right) & & {[}2+1+1{]} \\[15pt]
& {} + \cos''''(f) \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right) & & {[}1+1+1+1{]}
\end{align}
Finally, we let the four variables $x_4,x_3,x_2,x_1$ become indistinguishable and collect like terms:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^4}{dx^4} \cos(f) = {} & \cos'(f) \cdot \frac{d^4 f}{dx^4} + \cos''(f)\left( 4\cdot\frac{d^3 f}{dx^3}\cdot\frac{df}{dx} + 3\cdot\left(\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} \right)^2 \right) \\[10pt]
& {} + \cos'''(f) \left( 6 \cdot \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} \cdot \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^2 \right) + \cos''''(f) \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^4.
\end{align}
That's where the coefficients $\underbrace{1,\,4,\,3,\,6,\,1}$ come from.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the symbolic expression but only the Taylor coefficients at $x=0$, you can use Taylor arithmetic based on the differential equations of the sine and cosine (see automatic differentiation, autodiff.org for software). With $g(x)=\cos(f(x))$ and $h(x)=\sin(f(x))$ you get
$$
g'(x)=-h(x)·f'(x)\\
h'(x)=g(x)·f'(x)
$$
which allows coefficient computation by series multiplication rules. Let $f(x)=\sum a_jx^j$, $g(x)=\sum b_jx^j$ and $h(x)=\sum c_jx^j$, then at power $x^{n-1}$ you find
$$
nb_n=-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}c_j·(n-j)a_{n-j}\\
nc_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j·(n-j)a_{n-j}
$$
which allows the coefficient evaluation in a double loop, initializing with $b_0=\cos(a_0)$ and $c_0=\sin(a_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of evaluating

$$f(x)-\frac{(f(x))^3}{3!}+\frac{(f(x))^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

where the power of the polynomials are obtained by the multinomial formula. This will lead you to a complicated double summation, but a general formula anyway.

The coefficients of the resulting polynomial give you the requested derivatives.