# Power of a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $ f(x)$ has the convergent power series representation of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$. Then What is the power series representation of the function $\left[f(x)\right]^m$ for some integer $m$.  Or, How to find $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\right)^m$$

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_raised_to_powers).

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is this: the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of the series is the sum of all the distinct products $a_{k_1}\cdot a_{k_2}\cdots a_{k_m}$ such that $k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_m=n$, that is

$$
\left(\sum_{n\geqslant 0}a_n x^n\right)^m=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}b_n x^n\tag1
$$

where

$$
b_n=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_m=n}\prod_{j=1}^m a_{k_j}\tag2
$$

The index of the sum on $(2)$ means that you get all the $m$-tuples of $\Bbb N_{\ge 0}^m$ such that the sum of it coordinates is equal to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_raised_to_powers) in the comment of @metamorphy is obtained from the differential equation for the power, if $g(x)=f(x)^m$, then
$$
f(x)g'(x)=f(x)\cdot m\,f(x)^{m-1}f'(x)=m\,f'(x)g(x)
$$
and comparing the coefficients of equal powers on both sides gives for the power $x^{n-1}$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k\cdot (n-k)b_{n-k}=m\sum_{k=1}^{n} ka_k\cdot b_{n-k}
$$
so that
$$
na_0b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ((m+1)k-n)⋅ a_k\cdot b_{n-k}
$$

---

Similar calculations that are used in automatic/algorithmic differentiation in the propagation of truncated power series or Taylor series are

- [How do I take high order derivatives for a Taylor expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1903562/115115)
- [$n$th derivative of $\sin(f(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1886408/115115)